# Loop through folders and concatenate mp3 files with ffmpeg

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have many folders in one directory, each containing 2 mp3 files.
Hereby I can find the files:

```
first=$(find ./*/* -type f | sort | awk 'NR % 2 == 1')
second=$(find ./*/* -type f | sort | awk 'NR % 2 == 0')
```

I want to concatenate the first file with the second one in each folder:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:$first|$second" -c copy "both_"$first
```

I have found [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53675192), but I don't know if and how I can use it for my purpose.

directory structure:

```
folder "files"
  |
  |--folder1
  |      |--001_001.mp3
  |      |--001_003.mp3
  |
  |--folder2
         |--001_004.mp3
         |--001_009.mp3
  ...
```

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: Can you show an example of the directory structure that you have? What determines which file should be the first and which should be tho second (just sorting on filename?)

Comment: @Kusalananda – Yes, just sorting on filename, as shown above. The filenames have increasing numbers, on which I can sort them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it would be simpler and more robust to not rely on `find` in this instance. You have a well defined directory structure and there's really no reason to use `find` to traverse it since you know exactly where your files are.

Instead, use a shell loop:

```sh
for dirpath in files/*/; do
    set -- "$dirpath"/*.mp3
    ffmpeg -i "concat:$1|$2" -c copy "$dirpath/both_${1##*/}"
done
```

or alternatively,

```sh
for dirpath in files/*/; do
  (
    cd "$dirpath"
    set -- *.mp3
    ffmpeg -i "concat:$1|$2" -c copy "both_$1"
  )
done
```

This would loop over your `folder1`, `folder2` etc. directories, with the pathname of each directory in `$dirpath`.  For each directory pathname, the body of the loop would expand the `*.mp3` globbing pattern in that directory and then use the first two matches of that pattern to run the `ffmpeg` command.  No check is done to make sure that we actually get two matches of the pattern.

The difference between the two loops above is that the first loop does not change its directory to each of the `$dirpath` directories, and therefore `$1` and `$2` will contain the directory path of the directory. This is why I use `"$dirpath/both_${1##*/}"` to create the path to a file called `both_something.mp3` in the directory (the directory path has to be stripped off from the start of `$1` to insert the `both_` substring).

The other loop uses `cd` to change directory into each directory in the loop.  This way, the `$1` and `$2` strings would be filenames rather than pathnames with an initial directory path.  Since the `cd` happens within a subshell (the `(...)`), the change of the working directory is only affecting the commands within the parentheses.

Comment: Both codes work perfectly. Thank you so much!